# Reactjs: Obj is being reassigned when using in setState, something odd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So, I have this base object:

```
const obj = {
    name: 'bill',
    age: 44,
    cid: 0
}
```

and in various parts of my application, I "reset" to this obj on my state. Problem is, IF I try to reassign the obj, cid is always overwritten - if I explicitly reassign, it's clean.. ala.

```
// this is psuedo code, but this would break in that
// var2 now has some bleedover with other objects dirtying things up
this.setState({
    key1: [_.merge([whatetever], {this.state.var1}],
    key2: [this.obj]
})
```

note: when I log out 'this.obj', it was mutated someway.

```
// this way is fine

this.setState({
    key1: [_.merge([whatetever], {cid},{this.state.var1}],
    key2: [{
        name: 'bill',
        age: 444,
        cid: 0
    }]
})
```

but explicitly reassigning a whole object on 5 or so places is lame.. why can't i just reassign the obj reference. I've never run into this before in all my years... of course, it is a reassignment issue and perhaps something with es6 reverse assignment?

anyways your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
key2: Object.assign({}, state['key2'], this.obj)
```

Although it is strange to be using `this.obj`. Shouldn't that be either `props` or `state`?

I'm still not quite sure what you are trying to do by "*resetting*".

Comment: thank... I was actually doing somthing like this, problem was I brain-farted and didn't have that initial {}, to create the "new object"... thus I was overriding the obj.. thanks for the clarity. Sometimes i just need a new set of eyes! :-)